# How can I create a grabbing functionality in my script like googlemap

Tags: javascript, dom-events

In googlemaps `onmouseover`, on can grab/drag the googlemap.

e.g.

http://code.google.com/intl/de/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple.html

May I use the same functions in my script or how can I creating the same functionality.

Comment: What are you trying to drag? What have you tried so far? More info == more better.

Answer (score 0):

You could use JQuery for instance:

http://jquery.com/
http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/freebies/drag-drop-jquery-plugins/